# Using a where condition within an inner element in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to parse an XML document and store the data in an array using LINQ in C# where I have multiple inner element with different data their attributes with the same name and it looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Catalog>
 <Book ISBN="1.1.1.1" Genre="Thriller">
  <Title  PublishDt="2015-07-09">
   <Pty R="1" ID="Buyer_Company">
   </Pty>
   <Pty R="2" ID="Seller_Company">
   </Pty>
    </Title>
</Book>
</Catalog>
```

I am trying to store all the above data in an array I am not sure how to deal with the element `Pty` where I have to store `Buyer_Company` in `Buy` and `Seller_Company` in `Sell` as they have same Element name and Attribute name ID.

I got the remaining data as follows

```
 var result = doc.Descendants("Book")
        .Select(b => new
        {
            ISBN= b.Attribute("ISBN").Value,
            Genre=b.Attribute("Genre").Value,

            PublishDate= b.Element("Title").Attribute("MMY").Value,        
           Sell=b.Element("Title").Element("Pty").Attribute("ID").Value.Where......
Buy=b.Element("Title").Element("Pty").Attribute("ID").Value.Where......(this is where I have issues)
        })
        .ToArray();
```

**May I know how I can use `WHERE` condition in inner element and attributes of `XML` in `LINQ` in `C#` such R=1 represents Buyer and R=2 represents Seller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think in sequences.  You want to query over *all* your `Pty` elements, then filter them by the `R` attribute value, then get the property you want.

So your buyer id could be obtained by:

```
b.Descendants("Pty")
    .Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("R") == 1)
    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("ID"))
    .Single();
```

And a similar query for your seller id (change `1` to `2`).  Putting it all together, you might end up with something like this.  I moved the cast to the start of the expression to make it clearer what type your properties will be.

```
var result = from book in doc.Descendants("Book")
             select new
             {
                 ISBN = (string)book.Attribute("ISBN"),
                 Genre = (string)book.Attribute("Genre"),
                 PublishDate = (DateTime)book.Elements("Title")
                     .Select(e => e.Attribute("PublishDt"))
                     .Single(),
                 Buyer = (string)book.Descendants("Pty")
                     .Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("R") == 1)
                     .Select(e => e.Attribute("ID"))
                     .Single(),
                 Seller = (string)book.Descendants("Pty")
                     .Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("R") == 2)
                     .Select(e => e.Attribute("ID"))
                     .Single()
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a `Where` clause there then you will again get an `IEnumerable<XElement>` and from that either you have to pick one seller\buyer or else fetch an array of seller\ buyer. I have considered that you are going to have just two nodes for Buyer and Seller and accordingly the query is:-

```
var result = doc.Descendants("Book")
                .Select(b =>
                   {
                       var buyerNode = b.Element("Title").Elements("Pty")
                                           .First(x => x.Attribute("R").Value == "1");
                       var sellerNode = b.Element("Title").Elements("Pty")
                                            .First(x => x.Attribute("R").Value == "2");
                      return new
                         {
                            ISBN = b.Attribute("ISBN").Value,
                            Genre = b.Attribute("Genre").Value,
                            PublishDate = b.Element("Title").Attribute("PublishDt").Value,
                            Buy = buyerNode.Attribute("ID").Value,
                            Sell = sellerNode.Attribute("ID").Value,
                         };
                    }
                   ).ToArray();
```

Also, Please note you will be needing `Elements` instead of `Element` to fetch multiple `Pty` nodes.